# What this function is called....: $O(x)$

Tags: functions

I've recently come across this in a few lectures, I don't have a clue what it is called (hence, googling it is pretty redundent). I must have been asleep in a few Mathematical Method lectures early on. Specifically it is the mathcal O in this example expression:

$$
\beta=\xi^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\xi^{4}+O(\xi^{6})
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_oh) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the big O notation, and this notation is one from the class of notations called Bachman-Landau notations. Its use can be stated in simplified terms such as following: $f (x) = O (g (x))$ if there exists real positive quantities $x_0$ and $M$ such that $|f (x)| \leqslant M |g (x)|$ for all $x > x_0$. For a more detailed information, see [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1):

You may find some clarifying explanations here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

In particular read the "Infinitesimal asymptotics" paragraph.